# Convert physical standby to standalone database

Tags: database, oracle

I have a standard primary / physical-standby configuration (one primary, one standby), and would like to completely break the connection between primary and standby; converting physical standby to development database that is dissociated from primary/production system.

This seems like it should be fairly trivial, but doesn't really follow any documented procedures that I can find (most of which focus on switching over to standby for recovery purposes).

My gameplan is to activate the standby database by "simulating" a failover (without the primary actually failing, of course), following instructions here:
**8.2.2 Performing a Failover to a Physical Standby Database**
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41134/role_management.htm#SBYDB5176

This would entail running following on primary:

```
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH REDO TO target_db_name;
```

And then, if no errors, running this on standby:

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE CANCEL;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE FINISH;

SQL> SELECT SWITCHOVER_STATUS FROM V$DATABASE;
     (confirm result is TO PRIMARY or SESSIONS ACTIVE)

SQL> ALTER DATABASE COMMIT TO SWITCHOVER TO PRIMARY WITH SESSION SHUTDOWN;
```

Then, on both primary and standby, bring up in OPEN mode and disable further replication:

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2='';
```

I have 3 problems/questions with this approach:

As a general statement, this feels a little overly complex - is there a more direct way to do this?  For example, I'd like to be able to do this without having to shutdown primary database (which is required in order to run `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH REDO TO target_db_name;`).

Current output of `SELECT SWITCHOVER_STATUS FROM V$DATABASE;` on standby is "NOT ALLOWED".  I assume this status will change with the `ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE FINISH;` but would like confirmation of this, as I don't want to find myself in trouble-shooting mode.

Is `ALTER SYSTEM SET LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_2='';` the clean way to shutdown replication?  Should I instead `ALTER SYSTEM SET LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_STATE_2='disable'`?

Comment: I would love an answer to this question too. Did you ever find out or did you have to use this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

We did this yesterday: Turn two Oracle 11 databases that were primary / physical-standby into standalone / standalone. There are many ways to set up an Oracle physical standby system: With or without broker, data guard manager, in different [modes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/protection.htm#CHDEDGIF) e.t.c. pp. This is what worked for us.

On your three questions:

- The former primary kept running, no shutdown needed. We also felt
  that the procedure was more complicated and less well documented than
  it should be.
- you are probably right. We didn't switch over, but convinced the standby DB that the primary was lost and it has to take over, i.e. only switched the standby to primary ("ALTER DATABASE COMMIT TO SWITCHOVER TO PRIMARY WITH SESSION SHUTDOWN;"). But when I tried this without "ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE FINISH;", it refused ("ORA-16139: media recovery required")
- I'm not sure. To shutdown replication, we used the data guard manager. I expect you need at least an additional "alter database recover managed standby database cancel;"

---

preparation:

```
create spfile from pfile='standalone.ora';
alter database backup controlfile to trace;
```

in dgmgrl:

```
REMOVE DATABASE
REMOVE CONFIGURATION
```

on standby:

```
alter database recover managed standby database finish;
ALTER DATABASE COMMIT TO SWITCHOVER TO PRIMARY WITH SESSION SHUTDOWN;
```

(now this database is PRIMARY)

```
shutdown immediate;
startup
```

And that was it.

---

For cleanup, we modified the pfile:
  dg_broker_start=false
and removed
  dg_broker_config_file1 
  dg_broker_config_file2
  fal_server
  standby_file_management

and in sqlplus / in the database, we dropped the standby redo logs

```
alter database drop standby logfile group 30;
```

Comment: I suspect both standalone databases still have the same database id.  It would probably cleanest to give the previous standby a new identity
using the DBNEWID utility ($ORACLE_HOME/bin/nid).
See also Oracle support document ID 2074686.1 .

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast way to do it.
on standby

```
$  sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>  ALTER DATABASE ACTIVATE PHYSICAL STANDBY DATABASE;
SQL>  SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
SQL>  STARTUP
```

Also an oracle document is availble [2074686.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=87960689392225&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=2074686.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=ud08sttwp_4)